# How do i create a menu using print statements? I want to be able to choose a number and based on what number i choose run that function

Tags: python, function, menu

```
def main():

    option=displaymenu()
    print(option)
    while option1 != 4:
        if option1 ==1:
            print("1234")
        elif option1==2:
            print("1")
        elif option1==3:
            print("joe")
        else:
            print("end")



def displaymenu():
    print("choose one of the following options")
    print("1.Calculate x to the power of N")  << this is supposed to be 
    print("2.Calculate factorial of N")
    print("3.Calculate EXP")
    print("4.Exit")
    option1=input("Please enter your choice here:")<<<  i want these print statements to act as a menu? how do I make it so when I input a number 1-4 It does this operation I input ?
```

I want this to be a input statement that when I input 1 it will do print 1234 as I coded in my main program... help ? why when I enter a 1 or 2 or 3 it does nothing but print "end" ..? help.
    main()

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as "Accepted" if it answered your question and was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Your line `option=displaymenu()` will set `option` to `None` as you don't have a return statement at the end of your function.
Add the following line to your function and it should work:

```
return int(option1)
```

Comment: the "return int (option1) " is just returning whatever value is inputed correct @Energya

Comment: @Teante Mclin Yes, by placing ``return x`` at the end of some function ``foo()``, you can get this value by using ``return_value = foo()``. The ``int()`` function is to convert your input (a string type) to an int (number), to make sure the comparison in your menu works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning back option1 from displaymeny. Instead you are trying to access it in the main function:

```
 while option1 != 4:
```

This also means that option in the main function does not have any vaule.

Change your program to this:

```
def main():
option = -1 # Value to get the while loop started
while option != 4:
    option=displaymenu()
    if option ==1:
        print("1234")
    elif option==2:
        print("1")
    elif option==3:
        print("joe")
    else:
        print("end")



def displaymenu():
    print("choose one of the following options")
    print("1.Calculate x to the power of N")  << this is supposed to be 
    print("2.Calculate factorial of N")
    print("3.Calculate EXP")
    print("4.Exit")
    return input("Please enter your choice here:")<<<  i want these print statements to act as a menu? how do I make it so when I input a number 1-4 It does this operation I input ?
```

Also note that I moved the call to displaymeny inside the while loop. If you have it outside you will only get the menu once.

Comment: And yes, just as @Energya mentions, you should convert the input to int.

Comment: can you briefly axplain what the option = -1 is doing ? thanks @Joekim

Comment: only presets the value. You can set it to *anything* excepted `4`.

Comment: Just as @abccd says this is a starting, or preset value. As we want to compare option in the while loop the variable must exist and we need to give it any value that is not 4 as this would make the program never enter the loop. I used -1 to indicate that this is not any particular value used inside the loop.